# can we update the value of control variable in if else block inside while loop? If yes, then why my code doesn't works?

Tags: c

If I use `i=i+2` outside of all if and else if conditions inside while loop, it works fine
but if I use this way it ends up with an infinite loop. Why is it so?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[50];
    int i = 0;

    printf("Enter the string");
    scanf("%s", str);

    while (i < strlen(str))
    {
        if (str[i+1] == 65)
        {
            if ((str[i] == 48 && str[i+2] == 49) || (str[i] == 49 && str[i+2] == 48))
            { 
                str[i+2] = '0';
                i = i + 2;
            }
            else
            {
                str[i+2] = '1';
                i = i + 2;
            }
        }
        else if (str[i+1] == 66)
        {
            if (str[i] == 48 && str[i+2] == 48)
            { 
                str[i+2] = '0';
                i = i + 2;
            }
            else
            { 
                str[i+2] = '1';
                i = i + 2;
            }
        }
        else if (str[i+1] == 67)
        {
            if ((str[i] == 48 && str[i+2] == 48) || (str[i] == 49 && str[i+2] == 49))
            { 
                str[i+2] = '0';
                i = i + 2;
            }
            else
            {
                str[i+2] = '1';
                i = i + 2;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\n%c", str[i-2]);
    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: what happens if none of the outer `if` conditions are met?

Comment: Note: `str[i]==48 && str[i+2]==48` you can use char literals here.  `str[i]=='0' && str[i+2]=='0'`

Answer (score 0):

When you're tempted to copy/paste/adapt a block of code, you should take a step back and ask yourself "Is more code really the best way forward toward solving the problem?"

Here is an alternative version of what your code is doing. Notice that this does not 'mix' ASCII characters and ASCII character values. (I had to consult my ASCII chart to discover what 48 and 49 meant.)

This does not solve your "infinite loop" problem, but it should make it easier to spot why @dbush supplied the hint that he did...

```
bool matchOne( char *str, char *pat1, char *pat2 ) {
    return strncmp( str, pat1, 3 ) || strncmp( str, pat2, 3 );
}

int main() {
    char str[50];
    int i=0;

    printf("Enter the string");
    scanf("%s",str);

    while( i < strlen( str ) ) {
        char c = str[ i+1 ];
        if( c == 'A' ) {
            str[i+2] = matchOne( str + i, "0A1", "1A0" ) ? '0': '1';
            i += 2;
        }
        else if( c == 'B' ) {
            str[i+2] = matchOne( str + i, "0B0", "0B0" ) ? '0': '1'; // as given
            i += 2;
        }
        else if( c == 'C' ) {
            str[i+2] = matchOne( str + i, "0C0", "1C1" ) ? '0': '1';
            i += 2;
        }
        // else ????? hint hint
    }
    printf("\n%c",str[i-2]);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```